# PhysicsJS - How to find a body by its label (or other value)

Tags: javascript, physicsjs

How should the findOne method be properly used? (http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/docs/#Physics-world-prototype-findOne)

This code returns the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined

```
var theBall = world.findOne([{ label: ball }];
```

Comment: I think it does not expect an array but an object: `world.findOne({ label: ball });`

Comment: MiMo, that is the correct answer. It works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it does not expect an array but an object: `world.findOne({ label: ball });`